# Preventing access to login and registration script when logged in (PHP SESSION)

Tags: php, session

I was wondering how i can restrict access to users that is logged in.
I know how to do it the other way around eg. restrict access to people who is not logged in.

I want to do this because i dont want them to access login and registration when they are logged in.

Here is my session if it helps

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || !isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
//User is not logged in. Redirect them back to the login.php page.
header('Location: login.php');
exit;
}
?>
```

And here is the session when they log in

```
if($validPassword){

$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = time();

header('Location: index.php');
exit;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obvioulsy you have to check if user is logged in:

```
// login.php
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    header('Location: /somewhere');
    exit;
} else {
    // show form or whatever
}
```

Comment: Well that was easy, thank you. I didn't know the difference of checking if the user is logged in, or a user was not logged in.

Comment: Yea, still need to wait 5 mins for that, but i will do it :)
However, the else statement is not needed in my script.

Answer (score 1):

On `login.php`, check if they're logged in, and print an error or redirect them.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    die("You're already logged in");
}
```